# Is there a setting in Visual Studio to raise a warning or error when a method is used that can create unhandled exceptions?

Tags: visual-studio, settings

Basically at work I commonly run into code like:

```
double pricediff = 0.0;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(someVariable.ToString()))
    pricediff = Convert.ToDouble(someVariable);
```

Instead of something like:

```
double pricediff = 0.0;
Double.TryParse(someVariable, out pricediff);
```

Is there a setting within Visual Studio that can produce a warning whenever a method such as `Convert.Double` is used that can throw an exception and the method is not contained within a `try{}` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not.  Part of the reason why is that practically any method out there can throw an exception.  It would have to issue a warning for almost every method as virtually any method can raise the following

1. `StackOverflowException`
2. `OutOfMemoryException`

Add on top of that the much more likely `NullReferenceException` and essentially every method would be marked as "can throw".

It would be reasonable though to create a feature that marks for explicitly thrown exceptions.  VS does not have this feature but R# does (IIRC).  However even that is not foolproof because you can't see through interfaces.

```
interface IExample { 
  void Method(); 
}
class Class1 : IExample() {
  void Method() { throw new Exception(); }
}
class Class2 : IExample() {
  void Method() {}
}

...
IExample v1 = ...;
v1.Method();
```

In this same Method may or may not throw.  Whether it does or not cannot be definitively determined by static analysis in all cases.